# phpmyadmin Event syntax error while it works on the sql command

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

DELETE FROM Ranking;
ALTER TABLE Ranking AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
INSERT INTO Ranking (username)
select username
from Players
order by rank desc LIMIT 100;

This is the command i want to execute every 10 Minutes, i have a table which should constantly store the top 100 players. And it works fine if i input the command into the sql command line. But as soon as i want to use the same command to be executed in an event this error shows up.

[image]

maybe i am not understanding the limitations of events can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?
I am sadly using a Server which runs Maria Db. 10.1.48 so i cant use the new Windows functions like Rank()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are defining an event with three SQL statements, but without using a `BEGIN ... END` block around them. You need to use BEGIN and END if your event has multiple statements.

So your event definition should be:

```
CREATE EVENT ...
DO BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Ranking; 
  ALTER TABLE Ranking AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; 
  INSERT INTO Ranking (username) select username from Players order by rank desc LIMIT 100;
END
```

I suggest reading: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/begin-end

I will also comment that you can replace the first two statements with `TRUNCATE TABLE Ranking;` which will delete all rows and reset the auto-increment more quickly than using `DELETE`. If you only have 100 rows in the table, maybe you won't notice the difference, but if the table becomes larger you probably will.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah i am aware of Truncate beeing better but apparently its only better when the Table is big enough and this Table will constantly stay at 100. But i am not sure if thats true , just what i read